# How to resolve inconsistent environment - Jupyter Lab

Tags: anaconda

I tried to install graphviz but got a message that my environment is inconsistent. Looking at other posts I tried

```
conda install anaconda
conda install -c anaconda anconda
conda update --all
conda uninstall anaconda
```

but all failed.

When running  "conda update --all", although it looks as if it fixed the problem, running the same command again gives the same output.

When running 'conda install anaconda' it ran for 6 hours without doing much. Eventually I stopped it. Here is the screen output:

```
(base) C:\Windows\system32>conda install anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: |
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::ipykernel==5.3.4=py38h5ca1d4c_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::ipympl==0.6.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - defaults/noarch::ipywidgets==7.6.3=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::nbclassic==0.2.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - defaults/noarch::nbclient==0.5.1=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::nbconvert==6.0.7=py38_0
  - defaults/win-64::notebook==6.1.4=py38_0
  - defaults/win-64::widgetsnbextension==3.5.1=py38_0
  - defaults/win-64::_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py38_0
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry
 with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: \
The environment is inconsistent, please check the package plan carefully
The following packages are causing the inconsistency:

  - defaults/win-64::ipykernel==5.3.4=py38h5ca1d4c_0
  - conda-forge/noarch::ipympl==0.6.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - defaults/noarch::ipywidgets==7.6.3=pyhd3eb1b0_1
  - conda-forge/noarch::nbclassic==0.2.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
  - defaults/noarch::nbclient==0.5.1=py_0
  - defaults/win-64::nbconvert==6.0.7=py38_0
  - defaults/win-64::notebook==6.1.4=py38_0
  - defaults/win-64::widgetsnbextension==3.5.1=py38_0
  - defaults/win-64::_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf==0.1.0=py38_0
failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: /
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
Examining clyent:  23%|█████?                 | 41/176 [00:28<01:33,  1.44it/s]/
Examining libsodium:  38%|███████▌            | 67/176 [01:12<03:33,  1.96s/it]|
Examining conda-env:  41%|████████?           | 72/176 [01:13<01:42,  1.02it/s]\
Examining m2w64-gmp:  56%|███████████?        | 99/176 [03:40<03:11,  2.49s/it]\
Examining mkl-service:  65%|███████████      | 114/176 [04:38<06:29,  6.28s/it]\
Examining chardet:  69%|██████████████?      | 121/176 [04:40<01:08,  1.24s/it]/
Examining conflict for six htmlmin testpath ipython console_shortcut wcwidth cf\
Examining conflict for six htmlmin testpath ipython console_shortcut wcwidth cf-
failed                                                                         -

CondaError: KeyboardInterrupt

Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y

(base) C:\Windows\system32>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to install `anaconda`? Also consider using `mamba` as a drop-in replacement for `conda`.

Comment: Because the posts suggest to do it in order to fix the problem